# St. George's Monastery in the West Bank

Tags: religion, israel, palestine

I was fascinated to learn about [St. George's Monastery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/St._George%27s_Monastery_(Wadi_Qelt)), a Greek Orthodox site that was first built in the 5th century CE. It's obviously neither Jewish nor Islamic, and is located in a disputed territory 12.5 miles from Jerusalem.

What has been its fate as part of the larger history of and more recent political developments in the [West Bank](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/West_bank)? For instance, did it receive equal protection from both Israel and the Palestinians?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about what happened to the church during the great events of the 20th century but apparently no one does, so I'll try to provide some modern context.

It seems likely that like other Greek Orthodox churches this belongs to the Greek orthodox church. I did explore whether there was involvement of government conservation organisation, but I didn't find anything. Private ownership and maintenance seems to be the deal with [similar buildings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monastery_of_the_Temptation) in Israel/Palestine and specifically the Jericho area.

Looking at [the legal map](http://www.btselem.org/download/settlements_map_eng.pdf) and this [walking map](http://www.everytrail.com/view_trip.php?trip_id=1654211) it seems like the Monastery fits into either [Area C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Administrative_divisions_of_the_Oslo_Accords) or (more likely) the [regional council jurisdictional area](http://www.btselem.org/settlements/map_analysis). This means the area is under Israeli control, whether that be directly or through the settler regional council. So you can assume current Palestinian governance has very little to do with the place.

You can see [recent road development](http://www.globalpost.com/dispatch/israel-palestine/101210/west-bank-st-georges-monastery-peace) done by the Israelis that highlights acknowledgement of the tourist value as well as opposition by the Palestinians towards the road (Israeli presence) and perhaps even the presence of the Greek monks (*"Another Palestinian minister said the monks’ presence “gave a deceiving impression” about the status of the land around St. George’s"*).

Comment: Thx for your effort and excellent links +1.